# How to order bibliography alphabetically in latex?

Tags: bibliographies

I am new in Latex. I am using my own .bst file. Is there any way to order bibliography alphabetically?

My .bst file:

https://pastebin.com/7ybYdLaT

Thank you for your help

Comment: sorting is what bibtex does so yes, but almost no one writes their own bst file, I've only written a couple in 30 years using tex what features do you need that are not covered by existing ones (I have over 400 in the default texlive 2016 input tree) but for sorting, see the standard `plain.bst` style and the function `FUNCTION {sort.format.names}` and related sort functions defined there.

Answer (score 1):

That is really easy with `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]